# Returning Zero Snapshot Documents from Firestore Listener

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

Not sure why this is happening. Hoping I can get a second or third pair of eyes. See comment in code. Here's the code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class FollowerApi {
    func loadFollowers(onSuccess: @escaping(_ followers: [Follower]) -> Void, newFollower: @escaping(Follower) -> Void, deleteFollower: @escaping(Follower) -> Void, listener: @escaping(_ listenerHandle: ListenerRegistration) -> Void) {
        
        guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        let listenerFirestore = Ref.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_MY_FOLLOWERS.document(userId).collection("followers").order(by: "date", descending: false).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
            
// this (snapshot.documentChanges.forEach) is where I am not 
// returning any documents! The breakpoint skips the switch 
// statement and hits the listener at the bottom of the file.

            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { documentChange in
                                
                switch documentChange.type {
                
                case .added:
                    var followers = [Follower]()
                    let dict = documentChange.document.data()
                    guard let decodedFollower = try? Follower.init(fromDictionary: dict) else {
                        return
                    }
                    newFollower(decodedFollower)
                    followers.append(decodedFollower)
                    onSuccess(followers)
                    
                case .modified:
                    print("type: modified")
                    
                case .removed:
                    print("type: removed")
                    let dict = documentChange.document.data()
                    guard let decodedFollower = try? Follower.init(fromDictionary: dict) else {
                        return
                    }
                    deleteFollower(decodedFollower)
                }
            }
        }
        listener(listenerFirestore)
    }
}
```

I can set the data and send it to the database, and I can see that I clearly have one document there. But the Xcode console gives me this:
[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where does that print output come from?

Comment: The line `snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { documentChange in`

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

I had a collection pointing to 3 different documentIDs when I testing a feature. I had a snapshot but was returning zero because the database was confused by which to return. Thanks, Frank, for reaching out!